# How can a vacuum have a breakdown voltage?

Tags: charge, vacuum

[This question (What is the capacitance between the Earth and Moon?)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/111582/capacitance-between-earth-and-moon) on EESE makes me wonder:  How can a vacuum have a breakdown voltage?

If electrons can find the shortest path through a vacuum, how is that possible?  With nothing to carry the charge, I can't understand how the charge can traverse a vacuum.

The value for dielectric strength of a vacuum comes from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_strength)

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_arc

Comment: @user6972 that should be an answer...a good one too

Comment: You may find it interesting that even a single very highly charged body emits it charges due to repulsion between the free charge carriers without the availability of any other charged body in perfect vacuum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The electrons (torn from one surface (electrode) through, say, electron field emission, just move in vacuum in electric field to the other surface (electrode).

Comment: To what extent is this a property of the vacuum, rather than a property of the work function of the electrode surfaces?

Comment: I'd say the surfaces play the leading role, the vacuum's role being rather passive (the electrons do move in vacuum, and the electric field exists in vacuum).

Comment: The above is true for an electric field of reasonable strength and for a relatively long vacuum gap, when vacuum polarization is not important.

Comment: I thought electromagnetic fields might have something to do with it, thanks.